# How to loop through this json array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, for-loop

I try to loop this json but it is not working.I want to loop through the shops but it is not working

The json:

```
{
    "type": "shops",
    "shops": {
        "1": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "abcd",
            "open_time": "9AM",
            "closed_time": "9PM"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "efgh",
            "open_time": "9AM",
            "closed_time": "9PM"
        }
    }
}
```

The script

```
$.getJSON( "simple.json", function( json ) {
  console.log( "JSON Data: " + (json) );
    for(var i = 0; i < json.shops.length; i++){

        console.log(json[i].shops.name);

    }
 });
```

This doesn't give me any results

Comment: `shops` is not an array. It is an object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Comment: Can you please `console.log(json);` and tell me what it is returning?

Comment: it gives me [object Object]

Comment: As per the above JSON doc you provided that is not an array a single json document. You don't have to loop on that

Comment: as in?...please explain how can i access shop data

Comment: Do you want to loop through the shops?

Comment: If you are the one generating the JSON, perhaps you should fix it to be an array and not an object.

Comment: Recommend one is array or object?..the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json.shops` isn't an array, it's an object. You can use a `for..in` loop or `$.each`

Using $.each

```
$.getJSON( "simple.json", function( json ) {
  console.log( "JSON Data: " + (json) );
    $.each(json.shops, function(key, shop){
      //key will be "1", "2"...n
        console.log(shop.name, shop.id);
    });
 });
```

Using for..in

```
     for(var shop in json.shops){
        //shop will be "1", "2"...n
        if (json.shops.hasOwnProperty(shop))
            console.log(json.shops[shop].name);
     }
```

Comment: $.each will return property names here, `value.name` and `value.id` are undefined.

Comment: Hehe, just kidding ;) But you did make me retest it 3 times!

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande can i use just for loop without using for in?

Comment: @user3475082 You can't loop through an object with a normal for loop. You have to use the for in statement. You can just use jQuery.each if you don't like the for in!

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande when we are dealing with json is this correct?..i mean using objects without arrays?

Comment: in your example, you could perfectly use an array.  "shops": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "abcd",
            "open_time": "9AM",
            "closed_time": "9PM"
        },
       {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "efgh",
            "open_time": "9AM",
            "closed_time": "9PM"
        }
    ]

But your JSON is ok. You just have to loop it a little bit different!

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande how can i access that shop 1,2 part?

Comment: In my example, in each iteration you are accessing to each part. Or do you mean literally the "1" and "2", in that case, you could use "key" in the $.each or "shop" in the for-in both will have the key.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the comments, shops is an object, not an array. You can loop through all the properties of a javascript object using:

```
$.getJSON( "simple.json", function( json ) {
  console.log( "JSON Data: " + (json) );
    for(var key in json.shops){
        if (!json.shops.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        console.log(json.shops[key]);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.shops.length` is undefined, because `shops` is an object and not an array and doesn't (in this case) have a "length" property.  but every JavaScript object can have properties, and those property names can be retrieved as a list, which you can then iterate over:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(json.shops).length; i++){

    console.log(json.shops[Object.keys(json.shops)][i].name);

}
```

or, alternately, fetch the object's keys as an array and use the `forEach` function built in to arrays:

```
Object.keys(json.shops).forEach(function(element, arrayIndex, array) {
  console.log(array[element].name);
});
```

Comment: You first code section is wrong - `Object.keys(json.shops)[i]` will return a string key, not an object.